# How to color a Spotfire Table cell based on a date difference

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I'm using a Spotfire Table visualization to display a list of engineering reports. One of the columns reports the last time the report was updated (Last_Update). The column data type is DateTime and is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

I'm trying to color/shade the cell based on the difference between Last_Update and today's date. For example: Last_Update - TodaysDate = 65 would color the cell red. I'm open to using gradient or segment color schemes.

I've tried a number of ways (custom expressions in the *Colors* menu, referencing the value of an associated column already having the aforementioned calculation, etc.) and keep running into walls.

Are there any suggestions about how to simply achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need it to be Gradient of segment?

You could used fixed mode and add Boolean expression rule like

```
Datediff('dd', [Last Update], DateTimeNow()) = 65
```

If you need ranges you can build them easily

```
Datediff('dd', [Last Update], DateTimeNow()) < 65 AND Datediff('dd', [Last Update], DateTimeNow()) > 20
```